# Difference between make and make!

Tags: quickfix, error, makeprg

According to the help page the only difference between `:make` and `:make!` is that the latter doesn't jump to the first error. So why isn't `:make! <Bar> silent cnext<CR>` equivalent to `:make`?

I'm using the following compiler in `~/.config/nvim/after/compiler/python3.vim`:

```
if exists("current_compiler")
  finish
endif
let current_compiler = "python3.vim"

let s:cpo_save = &cpo
set cpo&vim

CompilerSet errorformat=
  \%*\\sFile\ \"%f\"\\,\ line\ %l\\,\ %m,
  \%*\\sFile\ \"%f\"\\,\ line\ %l,
CompilerSet makeprg=python3\ %

let &cpo = s:cpo_save
unlet s:cpo_save
```

If I edit this test file

```python
foo
print("foo")
```

`make` jumps to the first line, while `make!` followed by a `cnext` returns the error

```
E553: No more items
```

Is the quickfix list not being populated with `:make!`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because while `:make!` doesn't *jump* to the first error message, it actually sets the quickfix cursor at it. So when you use `:cnext` it will actually try to go to the *second* error, which in your case doesn't exist. (You can easily prove that yourself by creating a test case that produces more than one error.)

If you use `:make!` and then want to jump to the current error (which should be the first one), you can use `:cc` instead. (See [`:help :cc`](https://vimhelp.org/quickfix.txt.html#%3Acc).)